# How to make a vTiger crm custom module can only display for administrator

Tags: php, smarty, vtiger

I am trying to develop a custom module in vTiger crm, I have a  requirement that the custom module can only display for Administrator.

How to make a custom module only for administrator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to CRM Setting->Profile. Now select a user to which you have to disable the module. In that page click on edit and UN-check the box for the module to which you have to disable.